# Bootable ISO to USB stick xp quickest method

Tags: windows-xp, usb, multi-boot

My dog took a leak on my PC when I went out (ye funny), now it reandomly restarts - I'm convinced the HDD is failing because the Windows seagate diagnostic program fails on a few tests.

I want to run this prior to windows in an attempt to try and recover sectors, the program includes an iso which can be written to cd and booted, but i dont have any cd's. I tried using unetbootin to create the bootable usb from the iso file (SeaToolsDOS222ALL.576.ISO) but it doesnt work. When i boot from the usb hdd unetbootin loads with "default" in the menu. No joy booting though. I checked the usb hdd in windows and all the files are there, extracted from the iso file, wont boot though.

Any ideas? Im using windows xp.

More info - when the computer restarts (like i just did now) it constantly reaches the end of POST and then restarts in infinite loop. If I pull the power cable out it will get back into windows, the longer i leave it between attempts, the longer I am able to stay in windows until it restarts. i.e if i leave the power cable out 5 minutes it will stay operable for longer than if i had left it out for only a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the ISO file you are copying from on a network share?  I have had similar issues with using ISO files on unc shares with unetbootin, if its local try a different iso like opensuse see if it works.

Comment: no it is local. i have used unetbootin on this box many times for several linux distros and it works :s

Comment: Try making a FreeDOS usb boot stick, and manually copy the seagate tools (seatools.zip I think) to it run from there.  There are other users who report success using this method if you can boot off usb with other distros.

Answer (score 2):

Use [HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=197) to make a USB flash drive bootable.